# The correct way to delete a variable if it exists

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I try doing:

```
def create_l():
    if 'l' in globals():
        l.destroy()
    l = Listbox(root)
```

This works fine but it returns a syntax warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\l.py", line 4
    l = Listbox(root)
SyntaxWarning: name 'l' is used prior to global declaration
```

I am just wondering if there is a way to do this without the syntax warning.

Comment: is this a function declaration?

Comment: @MMF Yes, I changed the mistake.

Comment: Are you asking to delete a variable, or are you asking how to delete a widget?

Answer (score 23):

Use the `del` keyword

```
if 'l' in globals():
    del l
```

Comment: Can I have an explanation as to why this was downoted? I don't see what is wrong with this.

Comment: Although I didn’t downvote, but your answer does not solve the OP’s problem. `l.destroy()` is the actually correct way to technically “destroy”/“delete” a tkinter Listbox. The OP’s real problem will be the scope issues.

Comment: Excuse me for saying, but the question is: `The correct way to delete a variable if it exists`. The answer I specified is `The correct way to delete a variable if it exists`

Comment: You will have to answer the question in context (dealing with tkinter Listbox), don’t just assume “delete a variable” literally means to delete the variable, sometimes titles could be misleading. “A way to do this without the syntax warning” is the actual question.

Comment: @Splinxyy My advice would be don't try to give good answers to bad questions, it might backfire.

Comment: @abccd: the converse could be true as well, Maybe the reason the person is asking the question is that they really do want to delete a variable, but the code isn't doing that. Until we get clarification, as far as I'm concerned the question is asking literally how to delete a variable, not destroy a widget.

Comment: I came here based on the question title and this answered my question.  So this answer helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `global` key word when declaring the variable `l`:

```
global l #declare the variable as global
l = 'foo'
```